# Project Works on Unity but Export not Working

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

To be more specific:

This project is a sort of demo project that I'm retrofitting. Started this project on Unity 5 LTS and had this issue in the console:

Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 'prefab.IsPrefabParent()'

I have since opened it on 2017 LTS and works exactly the same, so its not because of the version or whatever. There must be some prefab of some sort causing this no?

When I export a build, there's no problem. I open the build and suddenly it seems to freeze on the menu page, none of the button are working (they were working perfectly in-game on unity).

I'm sorry that I don't have much more to go on, I'm not a wizard at Unity. If anyone has even the slightest hunch, let me know! I really want to export a working build :)

Comment: The experience works totally as intended on unity with or without pause error activated. But then when I export it doesnt work

Comment: When you say "Started this project on Unity 5 LTS" does this mean that the project and its prefabs were created in Unity 5 LTS?  If not, what version of unity was used to create them?